# How to return to app After Facebook Login?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-login

In my app I have to give option to `login` with `facebook` and once the `login` is done from the `facebook`, the user should be `Navigate` back to the app .how it is possible..I have Installed  `Facebook SDK` and Used the Facebook Login sample(`SessionLoginSampl`) in my code to login from facebook ..it works fine..

Now i want when i login sucessfully from FB it should return back to the app??

How it is possible..
if i change in the..

```
If(appDelegate.session.isOpen)
//navigate here for tab bar...but does not work
```

Answer (score 3):

In your .plist file you need to add a row called "URL types" it should look something like this. This will allow the Facebook app or Mobile safari to know where to take you after the login process is finished [image]

Also in your AppDelegate you need to add these methods

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Comment: hey it works...thanks...and how can i logout from fb .when app is close....or bcz everytime the user get logged in when i enter into app

Comment: Trying to detect when the user closes the app out might be harder than simply telling the app to logout when the app starts. Have you tried logging the user out in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method when the app starts?